# Google play real-time multiplayer concurrency - sometimes players pick the right answer at the same time

Tags: android, google-play, multiplayer

I'm currently developing a real-time multiplayer game by using google play API. It's a 2-player Q&A where the player has to pick the right answer before the oponent(but with more than 4 alternatives). What I'm experiencing as a problem is that sometimes the two player pick the right choice almost at the same time and then they both send each other a message saying they got the right question and it usually bugs the game. I already make sending the message to the other player the first thing to do when you answer correctly, but I'm still getting the same error. How can I overcome this concurrency problem?

Comment: This most certainly sounds like something that Google's API should take care of. Are you sure you're not using the API as properly as you should?

Comment: yes I am sure of it, I followed the whole tutorial here : https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer

Answer (score 0):

A Boolean variable set in a synchronized method.
answered = false;

Comment: I don't know what you mean by this, can you give me an example?

Comment: Sorry bit worse for wear .. Yuletide silliness. A design that checks a condition (answered) before proceeding <http://www.theothertomelliott.com/node/40>